# Showing full row at top of page for SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

I am hiding duplicated values in my report.  I only show those cells where the value is different from the one above it.  This makes it look like a series of inverted stair steps or half an upside down pyramid.

Data sort order is Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 ...

In the visibility property of the cell,

```
=Fields!DataSetField1.Value = Previous(Fields!DataSetField1.Value)
```

For the next cell, I set the visibility property to

```
=Fields!DataSetField2.Value = Previous(Fields!DataSetField2.Value)
```

Etc. Etc.

When equal it's hidden.  That way the client only sees the pertinent information.

BUT that also means at the top of each page, if we're in the middle of a group, the client doesn't see the other fields that are being suppressed, and may have to flip back a page or two to under stand the whole row.

For the first row of each page, I'd like to show the whole row, then go back to suppressing redundant information.

Is there a way to tell this is the first row of a new page?

As always, thank you fellow Stackers for your attention.

Comment: I don't think you can reference a row number within a page, only within a dataset or row group (although I could be wrong). It would be useful to see some sample data and the expected output as , my initial thought was "why hide duplicates, just use grouping". You might have good reasons but without seeing it I can't visualise it and therefore I can't look at alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

"KEEP GROUP TOGETHER"